# Remove HTTP Header from XML Stream

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

When calling the HTTP Get function I receive both the HTTP header followed by the XML text. The header appears to be causing an issue when trying to read the string with xml reader. Is there an xml function that passes over the http header and goes straight to the <?xml starting element ? Or is this something that I would need to parse out?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: 6sFY33DUeKUNghiXGCl1p1FrnzlzAZuwxmevZRNw3ZREbHe/3b8i65GywBFKtXtNJXd8fCfp3Zs=
x-amz-request-id: FAA2721945B7D34E
Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2020 17:13:52 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 28 Nov 2020 05:43:14 GMT
ETag: "829fd34710715b9879a0d9a15895cf86"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 8713
Server: AmazonS3

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<base>
        <config> ... rest of xml below... etc etc
```

Comment: What are you doing to get this content? I mean, show us a [mre]

Comment: The content is being stored in a string variable.

Comment: indexof('<') and stream position.

Comment: You are getting the correct results.  The XmlReader skip over the http header and you get the beginning of the xml.   It looks like you are using Postman to view data.  What is the error you are getting?